# Why is connecting to localhost not working when using PHP and curl?

Tags: php, web, curl, connection, localhost

I have been trying to connect to a local host, but it has been giving me an error message:

```
404 Page Not Found

The server cannot find the requested page: localhost/user-validation.php (port 80)
```

I have been trying to connect to a localhost server through my webserver (using curl) that is not local. I have looked at other stack overflow questions and have only found
questions relating to connecting to localhost through cmd. I am using curl with PHP.
Here is my code:

```
 $curlconnection = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curlconnection, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://localhost:80/user-validation.php' );
curl_setopt($curlconnection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($curlconnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curlconnection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);


$response = curl_exec($curlconnection);
curl_close($curlconnection);

echo $response;
```

I have tried looking at my fire wall options on my device hosting the local host server, but it that does not seem to work. Can anyone give me some help with this code.

Thanks Matthew.
edit: I am trying to connect from a webserver to a localhost using curl. sorry for any misunderstanding.

Comment: You're connecting, but it cannot find the page `user-validation.php`. Are you sure the file is correct?

Comment: you can remove the SSL specific options as you are not dealing with an ssl protected resource.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. I just checked and the name is right. I can copy the link and past it in my browser and it will load the right page. Thanks, Matthew

Comment: *"connect to a localhost server through my webserver that is not local"* - Can you clarify what you mean by this?  `localhost` is the local host for whatever computer is running this code.  If this code is running on an external web server then that external web server is making this request to itself, not to your computer.

Comment: You cannot connect to `locahost` meaning "your PC" from a external web server. 1) localhost ALWAYS MEANS ___This PC___ so it would mean the External Server when used there. and 2) as your PC is almost definitely on a private network NOTHING on the internet can get inside your private netowrk without an invite in the NAT or an opened and forwarded port on your router

Comment: @MatthewWright: Regarding the edit... *"I am trying to connect from a webserver to a localhost"* - Then `localhost` won't accomplish that.  Your specific computer is not **globally known** across **the entire internet** as "the server called `localhost`".  That server's code would need to connect to your server the same way any computer connects to any server.  It would need the address of your server, and your server would need to be reachable from outside your network (through routers, firewalls, anything else you have in place).

Comment: You could purchase a domain and get the DNS pointed to your Routers WAN Address, then open port 80 and forward it to the PC inside your network running the webserver. Or get a dynamic DNS entry pointing to your routers WAN Address and do the same

Comment: ...but don't do that unless you are confident you understand the security implications, and are also happy to leave your PC running 24/7, and you think the connection has enough bandwidth

Comment: Hi, This is just for development to see how two servers will interact and work with my program. I will not be using this for when the program is public. Thanks, Matthew.

Comment: Even just as a test, opening up your home network to the outside world still has security implications. It would be better to have two internet-facing servers to test with. You could just get a free hosting account or something, if you want to do an experiment. Or some cheap cloud server, perhaps.

Comment: Don't worry im not opening my home network. Im going to pass the valuables in a different way. I know the risks of opening removing the fire wall and opening my network to the public

Comment: If you are sure that you need remote server to connect to your development machine, you can use a tool https://ngrok.com/, which will create a tunnel from your computer to the remote server and tell server to proxy all the requests to certain port into this tunnel. Also there is a php-based tool on top of ngrok, with more user-friendly setup: https://expose.dev.